# AWS Glue write_dynamic frame is automatically adding double quotes to some records

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue

I've this code to write dynamic frames as files in S3 but it also wraps some records with double quotes.
Any idea on how to disable this?

```
format_options = {"optimizePerformance": True, "separator": "\t"}
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=dyf_frame.coalesce(1),
    connection_type="s3",
    connection_options={
        "path": outpath,
        "compression": "gzip",
        "groupFiles": "inPartition",
    },
    format="csv",
    format_options=format_options,
)
```

Example output.txt.gz:

```
name
NAME1
"NAME2 NAME2SURNAME"
NAME3
"NAME4 NAME4"
"NAME5 NAME5"
```

Expected output.txt.gz

```
name
NAME1
NAME2 NAME2SURNAME
NAME3
NAME4 NAME4
NAME5 NAME5
```

I tried searching for this case but was not able to find any relevant source. I need the double quotes to be removed because the records are loaded to redshift using COPY

```
copy staging.table(
    name
    )
from 's3://output.txt.gz'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::693485840050:role/test'
delimiter '\t'  gzip
IGNOREBLANKLINES
IGNOREHEADER 1
COMPUPDATE ON
NULL AS '\000000000000000000';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `REMOVEQUOTES` to COPY query

```html
copy staging.table(
    name
    )
from 's3://output.txt.gz'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::693485840050:role/test'
delimiter '\t'  gzip
IGNOREBLANKLINES
IGNOREHEADER 1
COMPUPDATE ON
REMOVEQUOTES
NULL AS '\000000000000000000';
```